# turn off iCloud backup for my application iOS sdk

Tags: ios, icloud

I have some problems because of iCloud and i want to turn off its for my app,how can i do it in the code of my application,i thought about my problem and the decision can be turning off the iCloud, thanks for help

Comment: Is the problem occurring because of your app running on multiple devices?

Comment: Using iCloud in your app requires using specific iCloud-related APIs. So... don't do that? Stop using iCould APIs? What part do you not understand?

Comment: no,i have some problems with photos,which locate in my app

Comment: i don't use iCloud in my app,but it synchronizes with my app automatically and i have some problems because of it

Answer (score 10):

If you store files in Documents, they will be backed up to iCloud automatically.  If you don't want that, the easiest way is to just store them somewhere else.  Library/Caches is a good choice.  If you really MUST store in Documents but you want to disable iCloud backup you can use the technique outlined here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: thanks for help,but i need to turn off connection of my app with icloud as a whole

Comment: It's not up to you.  If the user wants to use iCloud then anything in your app's Documents folder will be backed up.  The only way you can "turn off connection" is to not put things in the Documents folder.  Either move the files or fix the problem you're having with iCloud.

Comment: @jsd HI Jsd , is that Possible Can i take the backup every 30 Second and also put the button On/Off Sync iCloud backup inside the app.  i take the backup from below Code :  NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]; NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"]; Note *doc = [[Note alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage]; doc.noteContent = data; [doc saveToURL:[doc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) { if (success) {}else{}

Comment: @jsd is that possible i can Save that Database in Catch instead of Document. Awaiting for your kind response, Thanks in Advance..

Comment: If you don't want it to ever be backed up to iCloud then I would put it straight in Library/Caches and don't mess around with the "no backup" attribute.