# App rejected due to violation of iCloud Data Storage Guidelines

Tags: ios, icloud, nsdocumentdirectory

I developed an application and submitted to AppStore, but after few days it got rejected for violating "iCloud Data Storage Guideline".

I am only saving my "App.sqlite" file in the Documents Directory. 
Apple is saying "We found that on launch and/or content download, your app stores 10.4MB on iCloud".

I have installed the app in my iPods & iPhone 4S and I observed the space occupied by the app in iCloud in different sizes.

In iPod1- 3.2 MB
In iPod2- 512 KB
In iPhone 4S- 512 KB

I could not figure out what is going wrong actually. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why there is a big difference from iPod 3.2MB to 512KB?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110321/turn-off-icloud-backup-for-my-application-ios-sdk

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. Fortunately the app has been approved by Apple last night.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [iCloud storage guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html) only **user-generated** data can be backed up to iCloud and you shouldn't use the container to store any data that can be recreated, downloaded or regenerated by your app.

So, in theory, your app should not occupy any space at all on the iCloud just after the install. Bear in mind that the guidelines  state specifically where you should put app-generated data and temporary files that are necessary for your app.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. Fortunately the app has been approved by Apple last night.